When was $\mathcal{P}$ first used for power set?
Crossposted with Mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/476307/when-was-the-proof-wiki-mathcalp-first-used-for-power-set
The $\mathcal{P}$, as in https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:Fonts/mathcal, is now quite common as symbol for the power set.
When was it first used for power set?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
